# Selecting kids for a Christmas play with similar heights

Tags: c++, performance, programming-challenge, sorting, clustering

I am doing this [problem](http://www.spoj.com/problems/AMR10G/) on SPOJ:

> My kid's kindergarten class is putting up a Christmas play.  (I hope he gets the lead role.)  The kids are all excited, but the teacher has a lot of work.  She has to produce costumes for a scene with \$K\$ soldiers.  She wants to buy all the costumes in the same size, allowing for some small amount of length alteration to be done by the kids' parents later.  So she has taken all the kids' height measurements.  Can you help her select \$K\$ kids from her class of \$N\$ to play the soldier role, such that the height difference between the tallest and shortest in the group is minimized, and alternations will be easiest?  Tell her what this minimum difference is.
>
> INPUT
>
> The first line contains the number of test cases \$T\$. \$T\$ test cases follow each containing 2 lines.
>
> The first line of each test case contains 2 integers \$N\$ and \$K\$. 
>   The second line contains \$N\$ integers denoting the height of the \$N\$ kids.
>
> OUTPUT
>
> Output \$T\$ lines, each line containing the required answer for the corresponding test case.
>
> CONSTRAINTS
>
> - \$T \le 30\$
> - \$1 \le K \le N \le 20000\$
> - \$1 \le \text{height} \le 1000000000\$

My approach

I am first storing all the heights in the array and then sorting the array using quicksort (I also tried `std::sort`), and after that finding the minimum difference using sliding window (I do not exactly know the name of algorithm, I heard it is known as sliding window).

After optimizing my code to the best that I can, my code takes 0.05s to execute all test cases, but when I see the [best result](http://www.spoj.com/ranks/AMR10G/), it is 0.00s or 0.02s, so less than 0.05s.

By the way, I had also tested with `std::sort` but it was only marginally faster (0.05 s instead of 0.06 s). How can I optimize it more?

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <algorithm>
#include<iostream>
int partition(int *arr, const int left, const int right) {
const int mid = left + (right - left) / 2;
const int pivot = arr[mid];
// move the mid point value to the front.
std::swap(arr[mid],arr[left]);
int i = left + 1;
int j = right;
while (i <= j) {
    while(i <= j && arr[i] <= pivot) {
        i++;
    }

    while(i <= j && arr[j] > pivot) {
        j--;
    }

    if (i < j) {
        std::swap(arr[i], arr[j]);
    }
}
std::swap(arr[i - 1],arr[left]);
return i - 1;
}

void quicksort(int *arr, const int left, const int right, const int sz)
{

if (left >= right) {
    return;
}


int part = partition(arr, left, right);

quicksort(arr, left, part - 1, sz);
quicksort(arr, part + 1, right, sz);
}

using namespace std;

int main(){
int T,N,K,h[20000];

scanf("%d",&T);

while(T--){
    scanf("%d %d",&N,&K);

    for(int i = 0;i < N;++i) scanf("%d",&h[i]);
    quicksort(h,0,N-1,N);

    int ans = h[K - 1] - h[0];

    for(int i = 1;i + K - 1 < N;++i)
        ans = min(ans,h[i + K - 1] - h[i]);

    printf("%d\n",ans);
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: General suggestion: Do not try to overoptimise SPOJ solutions. Some people achieve fastest times on SPOJ by crazy fast I/O routines - and in some cases, by making quick algorithms which work for the given set of testdata but not for all general inputs. I would strongly suggest that you try to solve more problems and learn algorithms in the process instead of wasting time going for the fastest.

Also, why implement your own sort instead of std::sort?

Comment: You could try some O(N) sorting method like count sort or radix sort for example.

Comment: Quick sort is O(nlogn). Can you write solution in answer , i do not know these sort. You can write optimized solution below.

Comment: Try reading up and implementing these sorts. They will be very useful while solving some other spoj problems.

Comment: Optimizing I/O should boost time significantly. By "optimizing" I mean "reading whole data with `fread` in a single buffer and then parsing it manually". But I would also listen to @RazimanTV - there is very little point in optimizing such simple solution which does not perform very complicated operations (as opposed to, say, FFT). In this case, "micro-optimization" is pretty much guessing of how well your code, compiler and CPU will play together.

Comment: I get `0.04` using `std::sort` and `std::cin/std::cout`. Conclusion: Micro optimizations are not the solution. You should be looking for algorithmic improvements. Node: `std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);std::cin.tie(nullptr);` makes the stream library as fast as the C IO code.

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Comment: @Vogel612 Sir , I need to talk to you ?

Comment: Feel free to drop by in the 2nd monitor on [chat] :) I'll be there

Comment: @LokiAstari Can you give me your code , because i am unable to implement that http://ideone.com/vItolb see this what i tried just changed printf and scanf and did nothing else and it gave me segmentation fault

Comment: @LokiAstari  I tried your that optimization , i got 0.05 can you share your code .

Comment: @RazimanTV just saw you here https://www.quora.com/How-do-programming-contest-problem-setters-make-test-cases

Comment: @LokiAstari you submitted your code just now , it was0.05 right

Comment: @SurajJain: I have been playing with all different versions. 0.04 is the best I get without having to think about the algorithm.

Comment: Just add: `std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);std::cin.tie(nullptr);` at the top of main. Then use `operator>>` to read the values and use `std::sort()` to sort the data. Other than that my version is the same as yours.

Comment: @LokiAstari It does not increase speed as such , would be very minor so it is not noticable used putchar_unlocked and got 0.02 will write an answer on my own, still dont know how a dude got 0.00.

Comment: He got 0.00 by using a radix sort.

Comment: @LokiAstari how??

Comment: Radix sort is O(n). Reading is also O(n). So you can merge the loops into a single loop. Then just print out the result. How to do it I don't know. I am sure it is clever though.

Comment: @LokiAstari can you edit this code to show what you mean?   http://ideone.com/BArHyb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Time is mostly spent in I/O

I played with your program and found that most of the time was spent doing I/O.  However, from your comments, it appears you already improved your I/O so that your best solution is now 0.02 seconds instead of 0.05 seconds.

I took your improved I/O code and took it one step further.  What I did was read the entire input into a buffer using a single `fread()`, and then instead of using `getchar_unlocked()`, I just advanced a pointer through the buffer using `*p++`.

Why is `*p++` faster than `getchar_unlocked()`?  Here is what `getchar_unlocked()` does (not exactly but something close to this):

```
char getchar_unlocked()
{
    if (stdin.ptr >= stdin.buffer_len) {
        refill_stdin_buffer();
        stdin.ptr = 0;
    }
    return stdin.buffer[stdin.ptr++];
}
```

So for every character you read, it does a check to see if it needs to reload the buffer.  If you read the entire input from `stdin` to a local buffer, you are essentially skipping and end of buffer check for each character you read.

Update: Later I found that my I/O changes didn't matter.  Both yours and mine were able to achieve 0.00 time, as long as radix sort was used (see next section).

#### Radix sort

Radix sort is 0.02 seconds faster than `std::sort` for this test.  I know because I tried it both ways.  First I tried radix sort, which took 0.00 seconds overall.  Then I replaced radix sort with `std::sort` and got 0.02 seconds.

In general, radix sort should be faster than quicksort for large arrays of integers.  The radix sort I used operates on bytes at a time, so for 32-bit integers it uses exactly 4 rounds.  On each round it does a counting pass followed by a rearranging pass.  So in total, it does approximately \$8n\$ operations to sort an array of \$n\$ integers, plus a fixed overhead of 1024 operations to deal with the buckets.

From my own testing, I found that radix sort is 5x faster than `std::sort` for sorting arrays of 10 million integers.  For 20000 integers, it is around 4x faster.

#### The final program, which achieved 0.00 seconds

Here is my program.  You can see in the [SPOJ status](http://www.spoj.com/status/AMR10G,jsmythe/) that I got 0.00 seconds with it.  FYI, my first entry was a C program that got 0.00 seconds, but I changed it to the following C++ program:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <cstdio>

#define MAX                20000

// 30 testcases, 11 characters per number, 20000 numbers
char buf[MAX*11*30];
int array    [MAX];
int arrayTemp[MAX];

static inline int readInt(char **pPtr)
{
    char *p   = *pPtr;
    int   ret = 0;
    char  c   = *p++;

    while (c < '0')
        c = *p++;
    do {
        ret = (ret << 3) + (ret << 1) + c - 48;
        c   = *p++;
    } while (c >= '0');

    *pPtr = p;
    return ret;
}

void radixsort(int *a, int len)
{
    int *space       = arrayTemp;
    int *current     = a;
    int *scratch     = space;
    int *tmp         = NULL;
    int  radixByte   = 0;
    int  i           = 0;
    int  bucket[256];

    // Iterate once per byte.
    for (radixByte=0;radixByte<4;radixByte++) {
        int shift = (radixByte << 3);
        memset(bucket, 0, sizeof(bucket));

        // Count how many of each byte.
        for (i=0;i<len;i++)
            bucket[(current[i] >> shift) & 0xff]++;

        // Change bucket to be cumulative count.
        for (i=1;i<256;i++)
            bucket[i] += bucket[i-1];

        // Copy from current to scratch, using bucket counts.
        for (i=len-1;i>=0;i--)
            scratch[--bucket[(current[i] >> shift) & 0xff]] = current[i];

        // Switch arrays
        tmp     = current;
        current = scratch;
        scratch = tmp;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    char *p = buf;
    fread(buf, 1, sizeof(buf), stdin);

    int t = readInt(&p);
    while (t-- > 0) {
        int n = readInt(&p);
        int k = readInt(&p);

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            array[i] = readInt(&p);

        if (k == 1) {
            puts("0");
            continue;
        }

        radixsort(array, n);

        int diff = INT_MAX;
        n -= k;
        k--;
        for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
            int newDiff = array[i+k] - array[i];
            if (newDiff < diff)
                diff = newDiff;
        }
        printf("%d\n", diff);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How can radix sort be faster , i did std:sort with getchar_unlocked earlier and got 0.02 , how is that radix sort is faster , also i need to chat with you, can we?

Comment: @SurajJain I'm not sure why you think radix sort would be slower than `std::sort`?  Radix sort is not a comparison sort, and should be faster than comparison sorts such as quicksort.  If you just run my radix sort against `std::sort` for large integer arrays, you will see that it is much faster (as it should be).

Comment: Can we chat, some hours later , till then i will prepare list of things i am confused about , and learn a little more about radix sort ? , also i edited your answer , to link to spoj rank where your name is there with time 0.00

Comment: And See This http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/77529/why-isnt-radix-sort-used-more-often , this is one of the reason i thought quick sort is best , i have never heard of radix sort , so i will learn it first,

Comment: @SurajJain Well I don't agree with that answer regarding radix sort.  It should be faster than quicksort for integers.  But it isn't a universal sort because it relies on data types that can be split into digits.  Whereas quicksort can be used for any type that can be compared.

Comment: See This http://stackoverflow.com/a/41332552/5473170 , this is the thing

Comment: And Sir , i will talk with you , now i have to go to library , i will learn this radix sort , and other things and i am confused about buffer input and some things , and will ask all this later from you. I am awarding you bounty. Congratulations

Comment: Can We Chat? I have to ask some things.

Comment: @SurajJain Ok, [here is a chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53452/js1-and-suraj-jain)

Comment: I am there now.

Answer (score 2):

1. Fast I/O

   ```
   std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
   ```

   Or use `getchar_unlocked()` and `putchar_unlocked()` (this should do it)

   `getchar_unlocked` > `scanf` > `cin`
2. [Use `std::sort` over `qsort`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4708105/performance-of-qsort-vs-stdsort)

Comment: Any improvement with fast I/O?

Comment: Yes , i got 0.02 , and another thing is said in best answer , thanks for your help and can we chat ?

Comment: Radix sort plus fast I/O should do it. Sure.

Comment: How long have you been competitive programming ?

Comment: For about an year I guess. Ping me on hangouts or WhatsApp if you want.

Comment: I am not on whatsapp, where can i find you on hangout?

Comment: You just made an account here

Comment: Google my name, you'll find it. Nah, I wasn't very active here.

Answer (score 1):

1. Instead of rolling your sorting routine you could use `std::sort`.
2. Instead of:

   ```
   scanf("%d %d",&N,&K);
   ```

   You could do:

   ```
   cin >> N >> K;
   ```
3. <strike>`print (arr, sz)` seems to be a debugging facility. Consider removing it from your solution.</strike>
4. It might be good to isolate the actual algorithm in its own function, something like:

   ```
   int compute(std::vector<int>& vec, int k) 
   {
       std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end());
       return search(vec, k);
   }
   ```
5. If you remove your own `print`, you can also remove the parameter `sz` from your quicksort.

Comment: cin is slow than scanf

Comment: @SurajJain Did you measure? If it is, why C++ at all?

Comment: i measured it. i tried it in c++ with sort before , i did not changed it then

Comment: cin is generally consider slow than scanf and cout slow then printf

Comment: @SurajJain: `std::cin` is not slower than `scanf()`. This is a commin misconception; you forgot to add `std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);std::cin.tie(nullptr);` to uncouple the streams. Otherwise the C++ stream library is doing extra work. The problem with `scanf()` is that it need to parse the string at runtime to decide what to call to parse the input while `std::cin` knows which function to call at compile time.

Comment: @LokiAstari Can You Tell Me Good Source To Learn About All Of This ?

Comment: @LokiAstari I tried it , can you edit , the program to change scanf to cin  and that addign thing , i am having multiple problem when i do that ?

Comment: @SurajJain Yes? What can I do?

Comment: @LokiAstari I agree, but I have found scanf to be faster that std::cin with std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);

Comment: @RohanBojja: Note: That will may also depend on which version of the standard library you are using. `libc++`  as used by `clang` is slower. But `libstdc++` as used by `g++` is faster (it is the more mature version of the standard library).